# How to save data if the status is not active using mysql for vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

this is the first few days of my coding journey. For this code, Im trying to add a product in a table but I want to use a condition that will only allow it to add if the status of the product is not active or if its a new entry.

```vb
Public Sub checkitem2()

    Dim StatDel, StatAc, ProdCode, ProdStat As String

    StatDel = "DELETED"
    StatAc = "ACTIVE"

    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tbl_products where prod_code = '" & TextBox1.Text & "'"

    cmd = New MySqlCommand(strSQL, con)
    con.Open()
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()

    If dr.Read() Then

        ProdCode = (dr.Item("prod_code").ToString())
        ProdStat = (dr.Item("prod_status").ToString())

        If TextBox1.Text = ProdCode And ProdStat = StatAc Then

            MessageBox.Show("FOUND ACTIVE")

        Else

            MessageBox.Show("FOUND " + ProdStat)
            'additems()

        End If

    End If

    con.Close()
    cmd.Dispose()
    dr.Close()

End Sub
```

[image: Heres the pic of my Form]

Comment: So what's the actual problem? I see no attempt to save any data so I don't see that there is a problem yet.

Comment: Thanks for the reply jmcilhinney, i do have another public sub additem(), but this will save the data even if the status is already active.

Comment: `   cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tbl_products(prod_code,prod_name,prod_price,prod_weight,prod_brand,prod_manufacturer,prod_dateadded,prod_remarks,prod_status) " & _
                " VALUES ('" & Me.TextBox1.Text & "', '" & Me.TextBox2.Text & "', '" & Me.TextBox3.Text & "', '" & Me.TextBox4.Text & "', '" & Me.ComboBox1.Text & "', '" & Me.ComboBox2.Text & "', '" & dateNow & "', '" & Me.TextBox5.Text & "', '" & "ACTIVE" & "')"

            cmd.Connection = con
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            
    `

Comment: Don't put code in comments where it's basically unreadable. Your question needs to contain all the relevant information, so edit it to do that. No one should have to read the comments to understand the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tidied up your code a bit.

There are 2 important things to consider when working with a database.

1. Make sure your connections are closed. To accomplish this you need to keep you connection local to the method where it is used. `Using...End Using` blocks ensure that your database objects are closed and disposed even if there is an error. In this code the command and connection are both included in the Using.
2. **Always** use parameters. This protects your database from sql injection and helps avoid mistakes in types. I had to guess at the datatype and field size in your database when I added the parameters. Check for the correct type an size.

If you have questions about this code just post a comment.

```vb
Private ConStr As String = "Your connection string"

Public Function checkitem2() As Boolean
    Dim ProdStat As Object
    Dim strSQL = "SELECT prod_status FROM tbl_products where prod_code = @ProductCode;"
    Using con As New MySqlConnection(ConStr),
            cmd As New MySqlCommand(strSQL, con)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProductCode", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = CInt(TextBox1.Text)
        con.Open()
        ProdStat = cmd.ExecuteScalar
    End Using
    If Not ProdStat Is Nothing AndAlso ProdStat.ToString = "Active" Then
        Return False
    Else
        Return True
    End If
End Function

Private Sub InsertData()
    'Validation
    If Not checkitem2() Then
        MessageBox.Show("This item exists as Active")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    'The .Text property will not be Nothing. It is an empty String
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox2.Text) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Product Name must not be empty", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        TextBox2.Focus()
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_products(prod_code,prod_name,prod_price,prod_weight,prod_brand,prod_manufacturer,prod_dateadded,prod_remarks,prod_status) 
               VALUES (@Code, @Name, @Price, @Weight, @Brand, @Manufacturer, @DateAdded, @Remarks, 'ACTIVE');"
    Using con As New MySqlConnection(ConStr),
            cmd As New MySqlCommand(sql, con)
        With cmd.Parameters
            .Add("@Code", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = CInt(TextBox1.Text)
            .Add("@Name", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = TextBox2.Text
            .Add("@Price", MySqlDbType.Decimal).Value = CDec(TextBox3.Text)
            .Add("@Weight", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = CInt(TextBox4.Text)
            .Add("@Brand", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = ComboBox1.Text
            .Add("@Manufacturer", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = ComboBox2.Text
            .Add("@DateAdded", MySqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Now
            .Add("@Remarks", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 300).Value = TextBox5.Text
        End With
        con.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
    MessageBox.Show("Succesfully added: " & TextBox1.Text, "Info", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
    TextBox2.Clear()
    TextBox5.Clear()
    TextBox1.SelectAll()
    TextBox1.Focus()
    TextBox3.Text = "0"
    TextBox4.Text = "0"
    loadcomboboxes()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`
Public Sub additem()

```
    con.Close()
    cmd.Dispose()
    dr.Close()

        If TextBox2.Text = Nothing Then
            MessageBox.Show("Product Name must not be empty", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            TextBox2.Focus()
        Else
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text
            cmd.Connection = con
        con.Open()

            'ADD NEW DATA TO TABLE
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tbl_products(prod_code,prod_name,prod_price,prod_weight,prod_brand,prod_manufacturer,prod_dateadded,prod_remarks,prod_status) " & _
            " VALUES ('" & Me.TextBox1.Text & "', '" & Me.TextBox2.Text & "', '" & Me.TextBox3.Text & "', '" & Me.TextBox4.Text & "', '" & Me.ComboBox1.Text & "', '" & Me.ComboBox2.Text & "', '" & dateNow & "', '" & Me.TextBox5.Text & "', '" & "ACTIVE" & "')"

        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MessageBox.Show("Succesfully added: " & TextBox1.Text, "Info", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
        TextBox2.Clear()
        TextBox5.Clear()
        TextBox1.SelectAll()
        TextBox1.Focus()
        con.Close()
        TextBox3.Text = "0"
        TextBox4.Text = "0"
        loadcomboboxes()

        End If

    con.Close()
    dr.Close()
    cmd.Dispose()

        ' frm_Grid.prodlist()
        ' Application.Restart()

End Sub`
```

Comment: Edit the question. Don't post an answer that doesn't answer the question.